# Emacs fixed pitch text: Why Emacs uses Chinese font for it?

Tags: fonts

I use Emacs on Windows. As I have noticed while using `markdown-mode`, for fixed pitch text Emacs uses a very weird and ugly font, which is in fact was designed to show Chinese characters, but for some reason some Windows apps use it as a general-purpose fallback.

> If you want to test it yourself:
>
> 1. Install `markdown-mode` from MELPA Stable.
> 2. Type the following text to see how ugly the text in fenced code block looks and how everything below it jumps up and down.
>
>    ````
>    foo
>
>    ``` somelanguage
>    code
>    code
>    ```
>
>    bar
>    ````
>
> And then, to fix this problem, you will need to do the following:
>
> 1. Type `M-x customize`
> 2. Select "Faces"
> 3. Select "Basic Faces"
> 4. Scroll down to "Fixed Pitch face", click the triangle to expand it, and clear the checkbox.
>
>    [image]
> 5. And save changes, of course.

My questions:

- Does this issue is caused by Emacs or by Windows?
- The default value (before you clear the checkbox) is "monospace". Why Emacs uses this Chinese font for me for monospaced text? The default font for monospaced text in Windows is Courier New by the way.
- Do you have the same issue on another operating systems: Windows 10, Linux and BSD, macOS? (I use Windows 7).

Comment: FWIW, I cannot reproduce. I use this version: `markdown-mode-20201115.635`. Maybe there is a bug in the version you use (if different)? I'm on Linux though, not on Windows.

Comment: @NickD It seems to be an issue with Emacs or Windows and not `markdown-mode`. You will see the word `[sample]` typed in this ugly font right in front the checkbox even if `markdown-mode` is not installed. Here are screenshot and animated GIF: https://github.com/jrblevin/markdown-mode/issues/633